# Make Service start as late as possible during system startup

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, registry

I have a Service developed in C# DotNet (4.0) that is not starting at reboot. Although it starts fine manually. This happens on Windows 2016 Server, but works fine on other operating systems.

The Windows System Log simply contains an error that the Service did not start in a timely fashion.

I added a write to the application log as the very first action in the Service Main procedure. However after reboot this log entry does not appear in the Application log. So it seems that Windows is not even trying to run it.

Is there any Registry Value other than DelayedAutoStart (eg, Tag, Group, DependOnService) I can use to make this Service load as late as possible during system startup?  I'm thinking that might fix the problem.

Current Registry Values are:

```
ObjectName = LocalSystem
Start = 2
Tag = 1
Type = 0x10 (16)
ErrorControl = 1
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked application eventlog for .net runtime errors? Improve your logging with nlog/log4net step by step with file (and or eventlog) output. I never experienced a problem writing to the eventlog with services which have been set to startmode 'auto'

Comment: The message "the Service did not start in a timely fashion" usually indicates that you put too much in the `OnStart`. Make sure it returns as quickly as possible, and move time consuming operations to another thread.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Find out why your service “did not start in a timely fashion” and fix that, don't just decide to start your service later.

Comment: @DourHighArch - As I mentioned, I write to the Windows Application Log as the first action in both Service Main and OnStart. Those events do not appear in the Log after reboot.  So it is not even getting as far as calling OnStart. But thanks for educating me about the XY Problem.  Didn't hear of that before.

Comment: @dsdel - thanks for suggestion. No DotNet related errors in App or System Log.  I will try this on another 2016 machine.

Comment: yeah as the other guys are saying, there's usually a reason a service doesn't start, have you tried adding a UnhandledExceptionTrapper to your code in case that can tell you more?
for a work around you could set the service to manual and then call a batch script that does a delayed start, something like:
timeout 120
net start [serviceName]

Comment: @Angrist - thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned, the service starts just fine when started manually.

Comment: I meant you could try a delayed start using the Task Scheduler and a batch script that has the timeout command and see if that starts automatically in your scenario.

Comment: Researching a bit more it appears I am not the only one having this problem. Delayed Start seems to be the solution, but there appears to be something funcky with the Windows 2016 and Windows 10 Service Control manager.